# Help understanding a theorem about diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

So while studying for my Linear Algebra test, I'm required to study some theorems and their proofs, and I have trouble understanding a particular part of the proof for the following (I'm translating from another language, so I'm sorry for any mistakes):

> The matrix $A\in M_n(\Bbb{F})$ is diagonalizable **if and only if** the following two conditions are met:
>
> 1. All of the matrix's Eigenvalues are from $\Bbb{F}$
> 2. All of the matrix's Eigenvalues's algebraic multiplicities are equal to their respective geometric multiplicities.

I've also seen the first condition written as: "All of the characteristic polynomial's roots are in $\Bbb{F}$".

And while I have the proof for the 2nd condition pretty much pegged down, I fail to understand the first condition or its proof, which reads (again, crudely translated):

> The first condition is equivalent to saying that the sum of the algebraic multiplications is equal to $n$.

I fail to see how. In another source, I found it as:

> The first condition is equivalent to saying that the characteristic polynomial of A is a product of polynomials with a maximum rank of $1$.

And finally, this (directly from my professor's notes, and surprisingly - or not - the least helpful):

> "If $A$ is diagonalizable then all of its Eigenvalues belong to $\Bbb{F}$.

Very helpful.
I doubt I'll get any points if I use that one, though.

So while I see how the first and second sources are similar, I still don't see what the multiplication (or - similarly - the polynomial rank) have to do with the Eigenvalues being from $\Bbb{F}$.

Am I missing something basic? I'm I simply misunderstanding the definition?
Thanks in advance for any assistance understanding this theorem.

Comment: The Eigenvalues are the roots of the charateristic polynomial. They are always $n$, but they may not belong to $\mathbb F$ (for example the roots of $x^2+1$ aren't real). If $A$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb F$, then it's similar to a diagonal, and you may conclude observing they have the same characteristic polynomial

Comment: I see, and because a diagonal matrix's characteristic polynomial is the product of its diagonal, it's always possible to separate it to singular linear elements, which means the Eigenvalues will always remain in the same field. It seems so obvious when you put it that way, I wonder why they couldn't just write that in any of the source materials I'm using. Thanks! :-D

Comment: The word you're looking for is "multiplicity", not "multiplication".

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty much  translating it off Wikipedia.

Comment: I think the first condition could be replaced with: the characteristic polynomial splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}$. ?